# Most appropriate approach for saving item to array at same time its added

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've got an array of elements that needs to be saved to file whenever an item is added/removed from it.
Rather than having some sort of manager type class do this, i.e. in pseudo code:

```
- (void) SomeManager:addItem(Item*) item {
      [someArray addObject: item];
      save someArray to file;
```

I'd rather for example do something like derive a custom class from a mutable array and override `addObject` to additionally save it to file (probably using NSCoding/NSKeyedArchiver).

Its not recommended to inherit from NSMutableArray, so wondering what are suggestions for the most appropriate and simplest way to achieve this?

The app using this array is a mixture of Swift and Obj-C so the solution needs to be bridgeable between both.
I don't have a preference if any class declarations/implementations are done in Swift or Obj-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a class and call it DataHolder, DataContainer, DataStore etc.

```
@interface DataStore : NSObject

- (NSArray*)data;

- (void) add:(id)object toIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void) removeFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (id) getAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

Put your data inside it and manage it with functions. Maybe you can init with data and keep data private. So you can restrict manipulating data except functions.

```
- (void) initWithData:(NSArray *)data
```